# Application Should support 64-bit java

Tags: java, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am working on a application/product which is 32 bit and client wants to change it to 64 bit Java.
Please explain what changes I need to do, so that product start supporting of 64bit java.

Application is on JAVA, JSP , Servlet.
OS Supporting LINUX, WINDOWS

Comment: It is the runtime that is 32bit or 64bit. So you must simply install a 64bit JRE. The Java bytecode does not have this distinction.

Comment: but its using .so and .dll lib files from other application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All native code used should be compiled for the 64-bit architecture you use.
Java code itself is portable from a 32-bit architecture to a 64-bit architercture, though non-deterministic issues that are architercture-dependent can become visible. For instance, non-thread-safe code can behave differently on different platforms.

Comment: Can you please answere me what I have to do? When we deliver our product we bundle jdk 32 bit with it. So now what jdk we should bundle?

It support LINUX and WINDOWS. JAVA, JSP and servlet is used to create this product and on tomcat it is running.

So what jdk I should bundle with this product.

Comment: You should bundle a 64-bit JDK for your target platform. If your code is written in pure Java (i.e. no native code) then this is all you need to do, assuming that your application is bug-free. Though some stress testing would be needed to ensure it does not fail rapidly because of subtle bugs and/or assumptions that do not really work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...No its not pure Java, its using .so for linux and .dll for windows which are present in web/WEB-INF/bin/linux or windows.

Comment: You must re-compile your JNI parts for your new target platform then.

Answer (score 1):

The Java language and the compiled byte code is architecure independent. That means if you write a Java program (and you don't use native libraries), it will run on both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs.

So in Java code you don't have to change anything, moreover, you don't even have to recompile your sources because the byte code is also architecture independent.

Comment: So what changes i need to do. In the product we are bundling jdk 32bit and creating rpm for linux OS. As you mentioned above, I think we have to provide 64bit JDK to support 64bit java. Please clear me if I am wrong.

Comment: Read my answer fully: _"So in Java code you don't have to change anything, you don't even have to recompile your sources..."_

Comment: So what is required to support 64bit java.

Comment: If it's still not obvious: nothing. If you write a Java program, it can be run using both a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: Obviously if you are bundling the JDK in your rpm and you want to use a 64-bit JDK, then you need to include a 64-bit JDK.